# Dynamic Insert with Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

All I have the following two table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE ICD ([EpiNum] varchar(4), [ICDCode] varchar(4));
GO
INSERT INTO ICD ([EpiNum], [ICDCode])
VALUES
    ('1', 'A1'),
    ('1', 'A2'),
    ('1', 'A3'),
    ('2', 'B1'),
    ('2', 'B2'),
    ('3', 'C3');
GO

CREATE TABLE TempEpisode ([EpiNum] varchar(4), [X1] varchar(4), [X2] varchar(4), [X3] varchar(4));
GO
INSERT INTO TempEpisode ([EpiNum], [X1], [X2], [X3])
VALUES
    ('1', '', '', ''),
    ('2', '', '', ''),
    ('3', '', '', '');
GO
```

**I want to know how I can update `TempEpisode` so that I get**

```
    ('1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
    ('2', 'B1', 'B2', ''),
    ('3', 'C3', '', '');
```

**as the output?** Note, there a 3 codes for `EpiNum` 1, 2 codes for `EpiNum` 2, 1 for `EpiNum` 3. So I want to group these duplicates column-wise.

---

What I have done... I initially set out taking a pivot table approach; this has got complex and I am not entirely sure how I can get what I require from it. The existing code I have is

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(ICDCode) 
                    FROM ICD
                    GROUP BY ICDCode
                    ORDER BY ICDCode
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
PRINT @cols;

SELECT @columns = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', coalesce(' + 
              QUOTENAME(ICDCode)+', '''') as ' + 
              QUOTENAME('X' + ICDCode)
           FROM ICD
           GROUP BY ICDCode
           ORDER BY ICDCode
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT EpiNum, ' + @columns + ' 
              FROM 
              (
                 SELECT EpiNum, ICDCode, ICDCode AS flag
                 FROM ICD
              ) AS x
              PIVOT 
              (
                 MAX(flag)
                 FOR ICDCode IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) AS p ';
execute(@query);
```

This produces:

```
EpiNum  XA1  XA2  XA3  XB1  XB2  XC3
1       A1   A2   A3
2                      B1   B2  
3                                C3
```

**I want**

```
EpiNum  XA1  XA2  XA3
1       A1   A2   A3
2       B1   B2  
3       C3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
insert TempEpisode
select * 
from
( 
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by epinum order by icdcode) rn
    from ICD
) p
pivot (max(icdcode) for rn in ([1],[2],[3])) p2
```

Things that you need to consider.

1. How do you define the order of episodes - is there an extra field that isn't shown?
2. Is this a good idea - why are you de-normalising your data?

Comment: Q2. I will try this shortly. This is for data-ware-housing project and normalisation of the database in this case is not important for us. We are basically given tonnes of crappy data and sometimes we need to totally reformat to get what we need for forthcoming manipulations an to pull in to another _normalised_ database.

Comment: Q1. Well as you probably guessed this was a slim line test case. The real data is vast. The order of the episodes will be arranged via a group by/order by query on a date field. Then, (hopefull) using your example I will be able to push the icdcodes into the columns of the other table.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It is most appreciated.